# Android Google Paging library not working

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm trying to implement the google's paging library in my project. All things are already coded and network call is working in **loadInitial**() But it never goes in **loadAfter**(). As code structure is very complex I am not posting code directly here.

**Here's the repository :**

https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/PagingDemo

File link : https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/PagingDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rocky/invmx/modules/order/OrdersActivity.java

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: sadly no, issue is still there @jkistler

Comment: I couldn't find the code you're referring to, maybe I'm missing something or else, Can you point me to exact reference,

Comment: https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/PagingDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rocky/invmx/modules/order/OrdersActivity.java please open this file.

Comment: @jkistler solution is in the answers buddy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overriding `getItem(int index)` method in `GenPagingRecyclerAdapter.java` class without calling the `super.getItem(index)`. If you look at the `PagedListAdapter.java` and dig into the method call you will see that this method internally calls the `loadAfter` method. So first the solution to your problem is to remove the `getItem(int index)` from `GenPagingRecyclerAdapter.java` class. Because you are not doing anything in it and if you really want to override `getItem(int index)` then call the `super.getItem(int index)` at start.

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev please mark the answer correct and also waiting for bounty as well

Comment: you are the savior of the year, I was after this problem from at least 4 months. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RaghavSatyadev - thanks much! This solved a very nasty bug that I spent many hours trying to find. I'm not sure the documentation was very explicit about the importance of getItem.

Comment: Firebase documentation is worst. We have to check it on website everytime we want to know something. There is no JavaDoc in their code, which is very bad for the standard of Google

Comment: in my case i did override that method and still not triggered the loadAfter method , any reasons why guys !

Answer (score 8):

It is not an answer to the given question, but really similar problem.

In `onBindViewHolder` use `getItem(int index)` instead of getting item from `currentList`. As the accepted answer says - it is needed to call `getItem` to trigger `loadAfter` in `DataSource`.

Comment: Weird but yeah... You must call `getItem` to make `loadAfter` triggered. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: I also face the same. And calling the getItem() resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem of **loadAdapter()** not being invoked after **loadInitial()** has been called is to **REMOVE** the

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): YourDataModel {
    return super.getItem(position)
}
```

from you **RecyclerViewAdapter** that is **currently** extending **PagedListAdapter**.

Comment: its already mentioned in 1st answer. no need to create duplicates